# Different behaviours using `SingleChildScrollView` Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make the whole `OrderScreen` slide up when the keyboard appears as I do in `UserProfileScreen` by wrapping the scaffold's container in a `SingleChildScrollView`, but doing so on this screen it throws various `RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#abc84 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT` errors, which are not thrown without `SingleChildScrollView`. I set up the two screen just the same apart from `UserProfileScreen` having a `Column` as a child of another `Column`. All column's children are wrapped in and `Expanded` widget with different flex values for layout purposes. Can you se why I do get these errors?

## UserProfileScreen ( working ) :

```
child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.black54,
                padding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100, top: 30, bottom: 70),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                                  width: 2,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                              ),
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 50,
                                backgroundImage:
                                    NetworkImage('${widget.user.shopLogoUrl}'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 35,
                          width: 30,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Text(
                                AppLocalizations.instance.text('Shop name'),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white, fontSize: fontSize),
                              ),
                            ),
//                        SizedBox(width: 50),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: TextField(
                                          controller: _nameController,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                              fontSize: fontSize,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                                              isDense: true,
                                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                              enabled: false,
                                              hintText: AppLocalizations
                                                  .instance
                                                  .text(
                                                      'Shop name placeholder'),
                                              //'nome',
                                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: fontSize,
                                                  color: Colors.grey[350]),
                                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
//                              focusColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  width: 1,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                                              filled: true),
                                          cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),


...


                      ],
                    ),

                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //                                                          TODO cancel button
                          RaisedButton(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                                      child: Text(
                                        AppLocalizations.instance
                                            .text('Cancel'),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: fontSize),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context)
                                            .add(LoadUser());
                                      },
                                    ),
                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                          //                                                          TODO save button
                          RaisedButton(
                                      color: Colors.green.shade400,
                                      child: Text(
                                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Save'),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: fontSize),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context)
                                            .add(SaveUser(
                                          user: FixitUser(
                                              shopName: widget.user.shopName,
                                              email: widget.user.email,
                                              phoneNumber:
                                                  _phoneNumberController.text,
                                              uid: widget.user.uid,
                                              shopLogoUrl:
                                                  widget.user.shopLogoUrl,
                                              address: _addressController.text,
                                              zipCode: _zipCodeController.text,
                                              city: widget.cityUser,
                                              region: widget.regionUser,
                                              country: widget.countryUser,
                                              vatNumber: _vatController.text,
                                              homeLat: widget
                                                  .userLocation.latitude
                                                  .toString(),
                                              homeLong: widget
                                                  .userLocation.longitude
                                                  .toString(),
                                              lastLogin: DateTime.now()
                                                  .millisecondsSinceEpoch,
                                              signUpDate: signUpDate ??
                                                  DateTime.now()
                                                      .millisecondsSinceEpoch),
                                        ));

                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            barrierDismissible: false,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return Dialog(
                                                child: Container(
                                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
                                                  child: new Column(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .spaceEvenly,
                                                    mainAxisSize:
                                                        MainAxisSize.min,
                                                    children: [
                                                      new CircularProgressIndicator(
                                                        valueColor:
                                                            AlwaysStoppedAnimation<
                                                                    Color>(
                                                                Colors
                                                                    .redAccent),
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        height: 50,
                                                      ),
                                                      new Text(
                                                        AppLocalizations
                                                            .instance
                                                            .text(
                                                                'Saving user profile'),
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontSize: fontSize,
                                                            color:
                                                                Colors.black54),
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            });
                                      }),

... 

                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

## OrderScreen ( trowing error ) :

```
child: Scaffold(
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset : true,
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black54,
                  padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.redAccent, width: 2),
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 9,
                                child: TextField(
                                  controller: _customerNameController,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black87,
                                      fontSize: fontSize,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      isDense: true,
                                      enabled: true,
                                      hintText: AppLocalizations.instance
                                          .text('Customer name placeholder'), //'nome',
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: fontSize, color: Colors.grey[400]),
                                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          width: 1,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                                      filled: true),
                                  cursorColor: Colors.black,
                                  onChanged: (value){
                                    BlocProvider.of<OrderBloc>(context).add(LoadOrdersForCustomer(_customerNameController.text));
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(width: 20,),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 2,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                  child: Text(
                                    AppLocalizations.instance.text('Cancel'),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white, fontSize: fontSize),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _customerNameController.text = '';
                                    });
                                    BlocProvider.of<OrderBloc>(context).add(LoadOrders(user: widget.user));
                                  },
                                ),
                              )

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),


...


                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

## Progress

Adding height and width to the container got rid of the error, but the view doesn't slide up as `UserProfileScreen` instead does..with or without `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,` set in Scaffold.. the keyboard just covers up the screen..

```
child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.black54,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
              child: Column(
```

So I have two different behaviours.

`UserProfileScreen` doesn't need Container's heigh and width and it slides up on keyboard appearing.

`OrderScreen` does need Container's height and width but doesn't slide up on keyboard appearing.

Comment: wrap your row with expanded

Comment: @HamzaSiddiqui expanding the Row throws `Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.` error, You can in fact see that in the working screen I expand the children. Anyways the error is thrown inly if I use the `SingleChildScrollView` otherwise all the expanded widgets behave just as expected.

Comment: try giving static width to your textfield

Comment: @Dude Thanks for helping out. If you look at the code from `UserProfileScreen` I do use Expanded inside the scrollview right?. Am I missing something?